# what's the default behavior when webconfig doesn't contain <location path="">

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a web config with the following:

```
<location path="toolbar/apps/loginservice/login"> 
<system.web> 
<authorization> 
<allow users="?"/> 
</authorization> 
</system.web> 
</location>
```

if `<allow users="?"/>`  doesn't this means we can omit this from the web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.  This section may override other authorization configuration that exists higher in the application structure.  The settings you cited would allow anonymous access at this level, thus overriding any inherited authorization.

I infer this is a login page by the URL, therefore the likelihood is high that other pages do NOT allow anonymous access but this one does.

Answer (score 0):

If you  haven't set  `authorization` rules for the website as a whole you are right omitting it does have no effect because the default asp.net rule is `allow anonymous` or in short `allow all users`, otherwise it depends on the rules you set for the website as this one may overwrite the application level rules.

Comment: "Allow all users" would actually look like `<allow users="*"/>`.  This means that any user is allowed but they must be authenticated.  Otherwise your statements are accurate.

Comment: @pseudocoder: what if Elad is not doing so in his file. Elad showed us `<allow users="?"/>` which brings no difference if there is no website level restriction on anonymous users. In such case I said the default rule applies which allows all users indescriminately. I think now I'm clear. Thanks

Comment: Yes I agree with that point, what I was trying to say is only that "allow anonymous" and "allow all users" are two different things.  Your answer states they are the same.

Comment: Of course in name and purpose they are different but in effect don't they behave the same way

Comment: No, they don't behave the same way.  If you configure "allow all users", which would map to `<allow users="*"/>`, the configured page(s) will require authentication, while if you configure "allow anonymous", which maps to `<allow users="?"/>`, authentication is not required.  You are correct that the default effective setting is "allow anonymous", but that is not the same as "allow all users", as you said.

Comment: Hey I really became interested in this issue, I tried both on some pages in subfolder but none redirected me to the login page.  So I still don't see the difference, would you point me an example and let me try as a homework. Thank you for your time.